# Why is Redis returning 2 different types when the same key is accessed by 2 different windows?

Tags: python, redis

I'm using Python and the redis-py Python client to talk to the same Redis, which is provided by Redis Labs as Redis(e) Cloud. In the terminal, a key is retrieved and the value is returned as a string type.

[image]

Whereas when I run a code file in my IDE, the same code returns a bytes object.

[image]

I don't understand why they are returning different types. I blocked out the Redis host and port details, but they are accessing the same Redis, and I did not change anything between taking those 2 screenshots.

Comment: is your IDE using a different python version?

Comment: @olisch GREAT SCOT! Yes they were! Terminal was using python and the IDE had been set to use python3. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @olisch I had run pip install redis, and also pip3 install redis. Do you know why python3 is returning it in binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a redis issue but a difference between Py2 and Py3.

> Python 3.0 uses the concepts of text and (binary) data instead of Unicode strings and 8-bit strings. All text is Unicode; however encoded Unicode is represented as binary data. The type used to hold text is str, the type used to hold data is bytes. The biggest difference with the 2.x situation is that any attempt to mix text and data in Python 3.0 raises TypeError, whereas if you were to mix Unicode and 8-bit strings in Python 2.x, it would work if the 8-bit string happened to contain only 7-bit (ASCII) bytes, but you would get UnicodeDecodeError if it contained non-ASCII values. This value-specific behavior has caused numerous sad faces over the years.